# How to manage User authorization to upload images to S3 using AWS Amplify and Cognito?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have created UserPool and Identity Pools and performed Signup and SignIn successfully. But when I try to access S3 to upload an image, I receive below error.

Error:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: null; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

This is the code snippet which is causing the error.

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "MY_Identity_Pool_ID", // Identity pool ID
                Regions.MY_Region// Region
        );


        TransferUtility transferUtility =
                TransferUtility.builder()
                        .context(getApplicationContext())
                        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                        .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider, Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)))
                        .build();



        Log.d("imagepath", images.get(0).getPath());
        TransferObserver uploadObserver =
                transferUtility.upload(
                        "apples.jpeg",
                        new File(images.get(0).getPath()));
```

Comment: This error occurs due to the Authenticated IAM Role in Cognito Identity Pool not having enough permissions. I would implore you to perform a test via the AWS CLI, after creating a new Credentials Profile in the AWS credentials file.

Comment: @ArkaMukherjee You're right. thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by giving S3 access policy to authorized role in IAM.